# Why did Blender suddenly begin lagging?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

Usually when I use Blender, I have no problem playing animations except on the cycles engine. However, all of sudden I can't play my animation or adjust anything on screen without my computer acting as if cycles is on. This happened after I just the tile size in the render options then switched from Cycles to Evee. How do I get this to stop? Here is link showing what I'm dealing with:https://youtu.be/TipDNkmpLGM The only thing I wanted to accomplish was making a ponytail that moves. Here is what my model looked like before all this https://youtu.be/Wbz21wpydrI

Answer (score 1):

Steps of the viewport and render sections of the particle settings were too high.